# What happens if I run django migrations multiple times in parallel?

Tags: django

So, I often am working with projects where there will be multiple dockerized django application servers behind a loadbalancer, and frequently I will need to deploy to them. I frequently use Watchtower to do pull-based deploys. I build a new image, push it to dockerhub, and watchtower is responsible for pulling those images down to the servers and replacing the running containers. That all works pretty well.

I would like to start automating the running of django migrations. One way I could accomplish this would be to simply add a run of the `manage.py migrate` to the entrypoint, and have every container automatically attempt a migration when the container comes online. This would work, and it would avoid the hassle of needing to come up with a way to do a lockout or leader election; but without some sort of way to prevent multiple runs, there is a risk that multiple instances of the migration could run at the same time. If I went this route, is there any chance that multiple migrations running at the same time could cause problems? Should I be looking for some other way to kick off these migrations once and only once?

Comment: Did you find a answer? I'm working on a new deployment and it would simplify it to be able to run the migrate command in parallel. I've checked quickly the migrate command code and so far I haven't seen anything using a table lock or something like this. The documentation don't speak about it neither :/

Comment: Not sure. I ended up adding a tiny singleton server that just runs migrations and other one-off tasks on startup. It's the same image as the main application, but configured with a different set of environment variables. easier than worrying if the migrations were clean

Answer (score 7):

Running migrations at the same time in parallel is not safe. I've tested it by running the migrate command in parallel on a **data migration**, and Django will run the migration twice. It will add 2 rows to the django_migrations table.
Check out this [Google Groups post discussing the issue](https://groups.google.com/g/south-users/c/9TJuEf-gJEE)
And [this article about running migrations on container statup](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/schema-migrations-server-startup/).